# Unable to create Kivy executable with PyInstaller that works with Windows 10

Tags: python, kivy, exe, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create an executable that uses Kivy. I got the code and its dependencies packaged with PyInstaller but it only runs when I use Git Bash's ./ command to run the executable. I tried using the Anaconda prompt to run it and the debug message I got was:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x####### (DgApi64.dll) in App.exe: 0x####: Access violation writing location 0x######.
```

I also tried running it with Windows Power Shell and the shell freezes so I don't get an error message.

One possible lead that I have is that from the Anaconda prompt, I can see that the Kivy initialization process fails before it can output:

```
"[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system".
```

as it usually does when I'm running the .py file instead of the .exe.

The PyInstaller command we used was `python -m PyInstaller App.spec`

Our spec file looks like:

```
<code>
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew

# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['App.py'],
             pathex=['C:PATH TO CODE'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='App',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('C:PATH TO CODE'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
           *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='App')
</code>
```

Comment: What os are you running `Pyinstaller` on? What is the `Pyinstaller` command you used? Are you using a `.spec` file? If so, show it to us.

Comment: We are running it on Windows 10. The PyInstaller command we used was `python -m PyInstaller App.spec`. We updated the question with our spec code.

Comment: So that `.spec` file does not create a standalone executable, it creates a folder that contains an `App.exe` in the `dist` folder (I think it is `dist`). The executable must be run in that folder. Are you running it in that folder?

Comment: @JohnAnderson We are running it in the folder